# How to show a menu on top of the window's title bar

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying for some time now to show a menu like this one on my WPF title bar (the orange one in the upper left corner):

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/4.0_Windows_Theme%20_Mockups#Large_Button_Mode

I've extended the aero glass into the client area by using the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea method.
The application icon in the upper left is not visible, and I can show the menu, but one cannot click on it, it doesn't open, and if I put for example a textbox in the title bar, I can't edit its content.
I think that my controls are not on top of the title bar. How can I draw them on top of the title bar, so that the menu is clickable?

Answer (score 2):

The WPF Shell Integration library might help you to get this working:

[http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/)
(via
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2010/05/10/wpf-shell-integration-library.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/wpf-shell-integration-library))

> "The custom chrome feature allows
> applications control over the outer
> frame of the window so that WPF
> content can be drawn over the title
> bar. This allows applications to
> integrate with Aero glass to emulate
> the Office 2007/2010 look and feel, or
> to completely replace the frame with
> its own content without having to
> manage all the system behaviors that
> get lost when using WindowStyle.None"